# PrestaShop Smarty fatal error

Tags: smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am really new to PrestaShop and am facing trouble debugging an error in PrestaShop 1.6.1.3

It was working just fine, until I have changed some localization and delivery settings in admin panel.

Now, whenever I make an order, and try to proceed with bank wire payment, I receive the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Tools::getInvoiceProductName() in /home/makede/domains/manokede.lt/public_html/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(157) : eval()'d code on line 36
```

Any help or guidance for how to solve it or at least debug deeper is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by default class `Tools` have no method called `getInvoiceProductName` in Presta, if you added this line (where method called), just comment/delete it

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try clearing your cache and then check again?

Comment: Just did that, however, I still get the same error.